# ColdFusion allow user to download CSV file

Tags: csv, download, coldfusion, cffile

I am trying to allow the user to download a CSV file from the app. I have googled this a lot and as with almost any coldfusion issue I can't find much. Here is what I am trying:

```
<cfset yourFileName="\\10.21.2.187\devintranet\WebSite\Audit_Web\AuditWeb\temp\file.csv">
<cffile action="read" file="#yourFileName#" variable="myFile">

<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#listLast(myFile, "\")# />
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#myFile#" reset="true" />
```

This is the correct filepath:

```
temp/file.csv
```

and this is the file name:

Right now I am getting the error: 403 forbidden. 
I have no idea what is wrong and what is right about this. I'm just using code I found online. Any advice at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you print out `myFile` is it the correct filepath? (absolute path)

Comment: No? I didn't think it would be the filepath. I assumed since it said name it wanted me to just name it. I'll try again.

Comment: I edited the question to show what the actual filepath was. That said, when I put the full path into filename the same issue happens.

Comment: If I remember CFM correctly, it wants a full path `C:/User/temp/file.csv`

Comment: I edited the question again but now I just get a 403 forbidden warning.

Comment: The tag you want to use is `cfcontent`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Determine which file you want to download:

```
<cfset yourFileName="\\10.21.2.187\devintranet\WebSite\Audit_Web\AuditWeb\temp\file.csv">
```

Read the file into a CF variable:

```
<cffile action="read" file="#yourFileName#" variable="myFile">
```

Send the file to the browser using the correct mime-type and file name:

```
<cfheader name="content-disposition" value="attachment; filename=#listLast(myFile, '\')#" />
<cfcontent type="application/msexcel" variable="#myFile#" reset="true" />
```

Then there's no need for `<cflocation>`, the request will end once the file has been pushed to the browser.

**Update:** According to [CFDocs](https://cfdocs.org/cfcontent), `text/csv` isn't an allowed `type`. It *should* allow any proper mime-type, apparently it doesn't. Check that link for allowed values for `type`.

**Update 2:** `text/csv` was just fine. The `value` attribute of `cfheader` wasn't closed correctly. Had to change the `listLast()` to use single quotes and add a closing double quote.

Comment: This all makes sense except that in the line with <cfheader I believe we are missing a closing # somewhere but no matter where I try it I can't get it to work. filename=#listLast(myFile, "\") /> the # is opened at listLast and never closed. @Adrian J. Moreno

Comment: I see that you have updated the code and that error is now gone but I'm getting this error: Error Occurred While Processing Request
Attribute text is not allowed for tag cfheader pointing to this line <cfcontent type="text/csv" variable="#myFile#" reset="true" />

Comment: Attribute application is not allowed

Comment: Can you post your exact code? That error looks like you've done something like `<cfcontent applicaiton="something" ...>` where CF is validating against invalid tag attributes.

Comment: I updated the code to show exactly what I have right now.

Comment: @ColePerry I think I found the issue: The value attribute of `cfheader` wasn't closed correctly. Had to change the `listLast()` to use single quotes and add a closing double quote.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't see that either. Now I'm having an issue with the server being unable to hand the request but I don't think it has anything to do with the code not working I think I need to talk to the guy whose in charge of the server tomorrow. Thank you so much for all the help and being patient with me. Really appreciate it